# Char comparison in c?

Tags: c, string, char

I am trying the following code to try to find whether there is a comma followed by a semicolon in a char array. Here is my code

```
char m[80];
char *p = m;

while(p!=pend)
{
    char *pend = m + strlen(m);  
    int i=0;

    if(*p!=',' || *p!=';')
    {
        printf("DDD");
        char temp[2];
        temp[0] = *p;
        temp[1] = '\0';
        strcat( m2, temp );
    }
    else if(*p==',' && (*(p+1)==';'))
    {
        printf("CCC");
        char temp[2];
        temp[0] = *p;
        temp[1] = '\0';
        strcat( m2, temp );
    }
}
```

But the problem is, eve though input is, for example **12,;3** it never enters "else if" part. What can i do about it?

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Actually, i cant debıg it because i am writing this code in  a bison file.

Comment: Do "raise(SIGINT)" at the top of your function, and run it with GDB attached. You can't write good code if you can't debug it.

Comment: `use strstr(m, ",;")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(*p!=',' || *p!=';')
```

will always be true (`*p` can't be *both* `','` and `';'`).  Since the first `if` is always true, the following `else if` is never evaluated.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the first `if` block.  Maybe the simplest 'fix' would be to just delete that part of your code.

Comment: Thank you, i realized it now

Answer (score 2):

It does not enter the `else` part because the `if` part always evaluates to true (*any* character is not equal to either `','` or to `';'`).

Comment: Oh, yes how can't i realize this! Thank you!